# Convert FQL statement to Graph

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

With FQL being phased out I need to achieve the same functions via the Graph API.

My application checks for new posts, comments and replies on a company page every X seconds.

I use 1 FQL to get new comments and replies by doing

```
 SELECT post_id,time,fromid, text,id from comment WHERE time > (lastcheck) and post_id in (select post_id from stream where source_id = (PageID) limit 1000) order by time desc
```

This appears to work well ,I can add a comment to a 5 month old post and it picks it up.

How can the same be achieved with the Graph API?

Answer (score 1):

I think that if what you have works then you do not need to change it. Contrary to what Facebook wants you to do (use the graph api), not every query can be translated to it. FQL is alive and kicking and used heavily both in the Facebook website and mobile apps.

Comment: Thanks Mathew. Yes FQL is working now.. but Facebook are clearly stating it will be removed at the next API release. e.g Https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql I wont go into detail, but I must confirm it's possible to move to Graph now.

Comment: Correct. They were stating that at the recent F8 conference. However, although it is a good idea to move all of your queries to the Graph API, Facebook has stated that they will support FQL at least until April 30, 2016 - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog. For my team that means that we are waiting for API 2.0 to settle in and get some point releases / bug fixes before we start taking on an effort of converting all our FQL queries.

Comment: Thanks Mathew. Understood and maybe I need to wait to see if they release some more features closer to the date. I am close to releasing a commercial product but before its even sold, it already appears to have a limited life span. It could make for some very unhappy customers. :)

Comment: Good luck with your product! I hope it does well for you.